Error in plugin hardhat-ignition
I'm trying to verify my contract on the bsc testnet explorer (bscscan), but I'm getting this error:

Error in plugin hardhat-ignition: A network request failed. This is an error from the block explorer, not Hardhat. Error: Unexpected token '<', "
<h"... is not valid JSON

This is my hardhat configuration file:

require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox');
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-web3-v4');
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-solhint");

const BNB_TESTNET_URL = 'https://go.getblock.io/a3a4ef15f64942ccac82ff568ed2edb7';
const BNB_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY = 'myprivatekey';
const BSCSCAN_API_KEY = 'myapikey';

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.24",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 1000,
      },
    },
  },
  allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
  networks: {
    bnb_testnet:{
      url: BNB_TESTNET_URL,
      accounts: [BNB_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  },
  etherscan:{
    apiKey: BSCSCAN_API_KEY
  }
}



This initial task for deploying and verifying the contract:

npx hardhat ignition deploy .\ignition\modules\BigBang_LendingServiceModule.js --network bnb_testnet --verify

Deployment is successful, but when verifying , this error is received:
Verifying deployed contracts

Verifying contract "contracts/BigBang_LendingService.sol:BigBang_LendingService" for network bscTestnet...
Error in plugin hardhat-ignition: Verification failed. Please run `hardhat ignition verify chain-97 --include-unrelated-contracts` to attempt verifying all contracts.

For more info run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces

By running this task:

npx hardhat ignition verify chain-97 --include-unrelated-contracts

This error is received:
Error in plugin hardhat-ignition: A network request failed. This is an error from the block explorer, not Hardhat. Error: Unexpected token '<', "<html>
<h"... is not valid JSON

For more info run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces

I would be very grateful if someone could help me so that I can verify my smart contract in the bscscan through hardhat.

I'm unable to reproduce the error because both the commands are working fine on my end. Are you using the correct API key?

Can you share your code via GitHub repo, so that I can try on my end, maybe it's failing due to some version conflicts or so?

Thanks, this is my github repo, if you need security informations like my bscscan api key, I will provide you my friend, thank you so much again
https://github.com/se-ali-moghaddam/bigbang-contracts-tests/

Even, your contract is successfully deployed and verified on my end, when I executed this command npx hardhat ignition deploy ./ignition/modules/BigBang_LendingServiceModule.js --network bnb_testnet --verify.

I think, the problem is with your BSCSCAN_API_KEY.

Have you got that from BscScan Client Portal?

Yes I got that from BscScan Client Portal

Can you try using this API key: UWE3PMN8APVAIC6JBB4V69GPHG9MZWQDCS? I've just created it, and will delete later from the portal.

Delete the deployments folder (i.e., inside the ignition folder) and then execute this command: npx hardhat ignition deploy ./ignition/modules/BigBang_LendingServiceModule.js --network bnb_testnet --verify.

I get this error again:
Error in plugin hardhat-ignition: Verification failed. Please run `hardhat ignition verify chain-97 --include-unrelated-contracts' to attempt verifying all contracts.
This is my API key because I created my account just for testing, I don't care if this key is leaked from the security point of view
1DIYEA966GPR43UP3E7A9YKD7QGTT5D4KI

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In your shared repo (in the commit before you merged my PR), the problem is the missing dependencies / devDependencies  in your package.json file.
The content of your package.json file is:
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "hardhat test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chainlink/contracts": "^0.8.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^5.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-web3-v4": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.8",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-solhint": "^3.1.0",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.9.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.22.6",
    "web3": "^4.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chai-as-promised": "^8.0.0"
  }
}

After running npm install, then on compiling the contracts using npx hardhat compile, it throws this error:
Error HH801: Plugin @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox requires the following dependencies to be installed: @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers, @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers, @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition-ethers, @nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers, @nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify, @typechain/ethers-v6, @typechain/hardhat, @types/chai, @types/mocha, ethers, hardhat-gas-reporter, solidity-coverage, ts-node, typechain, typescript.
Please run: npm install --save-dev "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@^2.0.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers@^3.0.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition-ethers@^0.15.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers@^1.0.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify@^2.0.0" "@typechain/ethers-v6@^0.5.0" "@typechain/hardhat@^9.0.0" "@types/chai@^4.2.0" "@types/mocha@>=9.1.0" "ethers@^6.4.0" "hardhat-gas-reporter@^1.0.8" "solidity-coverage@^0.8.1" "ts-node@>=8.0.0" "typechain@^8.3.0" "typescript@>=4.5.0"

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH801 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces


You should execute the suggested command to install the devDependencies:
npm install --save-dev "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@^2.0.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers@^3.0.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition-ethers@^0.15.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers@^1.0.0" "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify@^2.0.0" "@typechain/ethers-v6@^0.5.0" "@typechain/hardhat@^9.0.0" "@types/chai@^4.2.0" "@types/mocha@>=9.1.0" "ethers@^6.4.0" "hardhat-gas-reporter@^1.0.8" "solidity-coverage@^0.8.1" "ts-node@>=8.0.0" "typechain@^8.3.0" "typescript@>=4.5.0"

Then again, on compiling using npx hardhat compile, it throws this error:
Error HH801: Plugin @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition-ethers requires the following dependencies to be installed: @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition, @nomicfoundation/ignition-core.
Please run: npm install --save-dev "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition@^0.15.5" "@nomicfoundation/ignition-core@^0.15.5"

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH801 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces    


You should execute the suggested command to install the devDependencies:
npm install --save-dev "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition@^0.15.5" "@nomicfoundation/ignition-core@^0.15.5"

After that, the contracts can be compiled successfully using npx hardhat compile:

NOTE: In your case, it seems like it isn't throwing the missing dependencies error, so you can just install them by replacing the content of your package.json file with the content of the revised package.json file, and then run npm install.
And, the revised package.json file would be:
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "hardhat test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chainlink/contracts": "^0.8.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^2.0.7",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers": "^3.0.6",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition": "^0.15.5",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition-ethers": "^0.15.5",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.11",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^5.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify": "^2.0.9",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-web3-v4": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/ignition-core": "^0.15.5",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.8",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-solhint": "^3.1.0",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.9.0",
    "@typechain/ethers-v6": "^0.5.1",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^9.1.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.16",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.7",
    "ethers": "^6.13.2",
    "hardhat": "^2.22.6",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.10",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.12",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typechain": "^8.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4",
    "web3": "^4.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chai-as-promised": "^8.0.0"
  }
}

Now, the contract can be successfully deployed and verified on bnb_testnet using this command:
npx hardhat ignition deploy ./ignition/modules/BigBang_LendingServiceModule.js --network bnb_testnet --verify



Thank you so much my friend

You’re welcome, Ali. Happy coding!
